# Creating app in Android studio but keep getting an error Required Boolean found int

Tags: java, android

So I'm creating an app that validates a users input but when I did it for the password all it says is Required boolean found int

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

   submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
   name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
   pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
   number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);
   email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);



    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

            final String Name = name.getText().toString();
            final String Pass = pass.getText().toString();

            if(name.length()==0)
            {
                name.requestFocus();
                name.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            }

            else if(!Name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
            {
                name.requestFocus();
                name.setError("ENTER ONLY ALPHABETICAL CHARACTERS");
            }

            else if (pass.length())
            {
                pass.requestFocus();
                pass.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            }

            else {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Thank you, your request is being processed!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

The error is happening on the line where it says pass.length. Could anyone please help in what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
else if (pass.length()>0)
```

instead so that you get a boolean value to use inside the if condition

Answer (score 0):

While using conditional statements you have to use boolean variable to check the condition is valid or not.

```
else if (pass.length())
```

Here pass.length() returns the length of the variable, which is an integer. You should not use the integer to check the condition.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast with e.g. C/C++ language, Java does not allow numeric values to be used instead of boolean values (0/1 != false/true).